# If declaring member data as primitive data types, will values be serialized if object is declared serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, wrapper, primitive

i have a question on whether the use of using primitive data type as opposed to their wrapper counter parts have any due effects on their serialization?

For example, i have a class Person

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
private int age;
}
```

as opposed to

```
public class Person implements Serializable{
private Integer age;
}
```

What are their differences?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm speaking in terms of Java's Serialization:

While `int` is a primitive type, which stores only the value of the variable (in binary), the `Integer` object (using `ObjectOutputStream`) will store some "metadata" that when deserialization occurs, it will see the `Integer` object.

Yes, serialization not only stores the object, but also the states of the object, so if you store,

```
private Integer value = 5;
```

The value is "wrapped" (lack of better word) inside `Integer` and the whole object is stored.

Added note: In order **not** to store an object/variable, mark the field with a `transient`, .e.g

```
transient private Integer value = 5;
```

**Related Resources:**

- [Discover the secrets of the Java Serialization API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html)

Answer (score 9):

Well, the exact serialization format will be slightly different (just the 32 bits versus a serialized Integer object containing the 32 bits and a header), but both will be serialized and deserialized just fine.

> If declaring member data as primitive data types, will values be serialized if object is declared serializable?

Yes, everything that is not marked `transient` will be serialized, including primitives.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: Somebody over my shoulder told me, to use Integer as opposed to int, because Serialization will not cover int, but Integer.